# Why 7Plus is not working in my windows 10?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, documents, files-folders

**7Plus** is useful to create **New Text Document** on Windows 10 Explorer using **custom keyboard shortcut**. But 7Plus is difficult to open now, why?

It open and stay in the system tray for a few seconds, and the windows (mouse pointer moving) slow down. Then, the software (7plus) closed by itself.

I used **F7** to create **New Text Document** and **F8** to create **New Folder**.

**7Plus** is useful to me. Please help.

Comment: Have you asked the app developer about their product? [7Plus is hard to google because predominantly results are about the Australian TV streaming company]

Comment: `7Plus is difficult to open now...` What changed?  What is the behavior that is now "difficult"?  Please add some details to your question that explains your problem completely.

Comment: I didn't ask the app developer yet.

Comment: It open and stay in the system tray for a few seconds, and the windows (mouse pointer moving) slow down. Then, the software (7plus) closed by itself.

Comment: Ok.  It sounds like it is crashing, in which case you should contact the developer for technical support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall it, clean up its folder(s) and reinstall? Use [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/) to uninstall.

Comment: Yes, I download a new one from the internet and reinstalled. But it doesn't work.

Comment: It also might help for you to provide us with a link where to get it.  As @Tetsujin points out.. we can't even lookup information on it or run it in a VM.  Many of us know how to monitor a program when it crashes.

Comment: Probably [Speed Up Your Windows Workflow with 7Plus - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/04/01/speed-up-your-windows-workflow-with-7plus/) and abandoned by the developer.